How can I configure prettier to stop turning "&gt;" into "& gt;"?
My work situation does not allow the use of some characters such as ">", "<", or "&". Instead, we use the html entity equivalent in the JavaScript.
Prettier keeps adding a space between my the characters in my HTML entity. How can I configure it to stop doing that?
Thanks!
I tried setting: htmlWhitespaceSensitivity to both 'ignore', and to 'strict'. Neither of those options worked.

if your "work situation" (?) "does not allow" (?) the & symbol, how do you use it to make HTML entities, which are introduced with &?
